# Why does this close immediately in Visual Studio c# console application?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, console-application

```
{
   class Program
   {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {

          Console.WriteLine("press enter to contiune");

          //math tutorial 
          Console.WriteLine("5 + 3 = " + (5 + 3));
          Console.WriteLine("5 - 3 = " + (5 - 3));
          Console.WriteLine("5 * 3 = " + (5 * 3));
          Console.WriteLine("5 / 3 = " + (5 / 3));

          Console.ReadLine();
          // casting
          //boolian
          double Pi = 31.4;
          int intPi = (int)Pi;

          //Math Functions
          // Acos Asin Atan Atan2 Cos Cosh Exp Log Sin Sinh Tan Tanh

          double num1 = 10.5;
          double num2 = 15;
          Console.WriteLine("Math.Max(num1, num2)" + Math.Max(num1, num2));
          Console.WriteLine("Math.Min(num1, num2)" + Math.Max(num1, num2));
          // other options: Abs Ceiling Floor Pow Round Sqrt

          Console.ReadLine();
      }
   }
}
```

//with the f5 debug is just says press enter etc. 
//really unsure cant find a solution to it

Comment: What happens when you run it? When I run it, it stops on the `Console.ReadLine()` method, just as it should.

Comment: You might want to add another `WriteLine()` at the end, just before the last `ReadLine()`, that says "Press any Key to exit".

Comment: It works as it should for me, too. Using Visual Studio 2015 Community. What are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can attempt this,

In Visual Studio: choose **Debug** menu, select **Options and Settings**,
inside **Debugging / General** node, clear **Enable Just My Code**.

Later, compile your solution in Release mode and execute it.